# jquery focus acting odd, only works first time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hava a dynamic table with an id='scanTable'.
When the below function is called, a new row is added to the table and focus is set on the first element of the new row. It works perfect the for the first row, but every following row, the focus goes to the address bar. The function needs to be triggered by tabbing from the last element in the row.

```
function addNewRow() {
    elementName = inputType + '_' + rowCounter;
    var newRow = '<tr><td>' + rowCounter + '</td><td><input name="' + elementName + '" type="text" id="' + elementName + '" ></td><td><input type="text" name="serial_' + rowCounter + '" id="serial_' + rowCounter + '" onBlur="serialBlur()"></td></tr>';    
    $('#scanTable tr:last').after(newRow);
    $('#' + elementName).focus();
    //document.getElementById(elementName).focus();
    // for testing, value is being set
    $('#' + elementName).val(elementName); 
    rowCounter++;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/99fdtLqt/)

Comment: Can you verify that the var rowCounter is actually incrementing and the IDs are properly changing?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: yes, that is why i added the 'elementName' var in the value field.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ve0s0pbz/

Comment: Did you try with a non-variable prefix and only a variable suffix, f.e. `elementName = "row" + rowCounter;`?

Comment: It's worth noting I have seen browser-specific bugs with focus before. Might be worth mentioning your browser version and the OS you're using it on.

Comment: fiddle example <https://jsfiddle.net/99fdtLqt/>

Comment: @Guinn yes, that is what i had originally

Comment: browser is chrome42.0.2311.135 m

Comment: your jsfiddle works, when clicking the serial and clicking away the new element has focus

Comment: @user3468982  yes, on a mouse click, it does.   I need it to work from a TAB key. I should have stated this.

Comment: Then it's not odd behavior, hold shift while tabbing and you will see it works. The reason it's happening is because you are tabbing out of the last element.

Comment: see my new answer to fix your problem

Comment: Unfortunately that is not an option, this will be working from a scan gun. the suffix is a tab key. I have done this before and not had an issue... very odd

Comment: the tab still happens, you're just preventing its default behavior

Comment: @loli  Thanks! you helped me figure out the answer. I added an button at the bottom, it receives the focus on the tab event but is within the area for the .focus() to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to disable the tab behavior of your serial input

```
function addNewRow() {
    elementName = inputType + '_' + rowCounter;
    var newRow = '<tr><td>' + rowCounter + '</td><td><input name="' + elementName + '" type="text" id="' + elementName + '" ></td><td><input type="text" name="serial_' + rowCounter + '" id="serial_' + rowCounter + '"></td></tr>';    
    $('#scanTable tr:last').after(newRow);
    $('#serial_' + rowCounter).on('keydown', function(e) {
    if(e.which == 9) { e.preventDefault();addNewRow();}
    });
    $('#' + elementName).focus();
    //document.getElementById(elementName).focus();
    // for testing, value is being set
    $('#' + elementName).val(elementName); 
    rowCounter++;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/99fdtLqt/3/

Answer (score 2):

I am unable to assume everything, but for me this following code is working. Where `rowCounter` and `inputType` is global variables.

```
function addNewRow() {
    elementName = inputType + '_' + rowCounter;
    var newRow = '<tr><td>' + rowCounter + '</td><td><input name="' + elementName + '" type="text" id="' + elementName + '" ></td><td><input type="text" name="serial_' + rowCounter + '" id="serial_' + rowCounter + '" onBlur="serialBlur()"></td></tr>';    
    $('#scanTable tr:last').after(newRow);
    $('#' + elementName).focus();
    $('#' + elementName).val(elementName); 
    rowCounter++;
}
```

[**See it in Action**](http://jsfiddle.net/hfqsbray/)

> In this demo focus is always going to first element of new row.

Comment: This works from a button, my trigger is an onBlur event from a textbox. See fiddle example.